# How do I get a long documentation string into a c/c++ program?

Tags: c++, c, string, documentation

I have a small library with some documentation that should be available at runtime, but the MS Visual Studio C++ compiller only allows string literals with length up to [2,048 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx08afx2.aspx), Is there a simple way arround this limitation? The only solution I could find was to make a string array and then allocate a new buffer and copy the strings into.

```c
char *doc_arr[] = {
    "Documentation for my program\n",
    "\n",
    "This is a seccond line\n",
    // and so on ....
}
int doc_arr_length = 203; // number lines in doc_arr
char doc[3502];           // number of bytes in dockumentation

strcpy(doc, doc_arr[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < doc_arr_length; i++){
    strcat(doc, doc_arr[i]);
}
```

**UPDATE**:
It looks like some context is needed.

I have a ruby program that takes a lot of options and gather lots of data and generate a .c file. The .c files is compiled to a .dll witch is then used in other programs for fast calculations. This means that you quickly get lots of different .c and .dll and it gets hard to manage versions. I think that i might be a good idea to include synthesized documentation on the options given to the ruby script in the source file and compiled dll.

Comment: Will it avoid this limitation when joining two literals by juxtaposition (`"2K-string-one" "2K-string-two"`)?

Comment: You have an error in your loop condition.

Comment: Fixed the error, and juxtraposition only makes the problem worse as a byte is vasted when the strings are joined(see link).

Comment: The text in the link doesn't make sense to me.  The last paragraph implies that using juxtaposition you can get a string of up to approximately 65K characters.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I did not understand the last paragraph either, but 

char *doc = "Doc" " Doc" " More Doc" ... Does not break the 2048 limit

Answer (score 7):

Answering your question with a better (IMO) alternative:

Distribute the documentation in a separate file. At run-time, open the file and read from it whatever you need.

External documentation has no place in code.

Comment: Yes, in most cases I agree. An extra file is possible, and might be the solution we will use. It adds complexity and to handle different files, when there is just a few hounded lines of documentation I want to include in the source and compiled .dll

Comment: @ivarne A few hundred lines of documentation **now**. It can increase. It probably will.

Comment: No, the runtime documentation will probably be shorter when it is rewritten and even shorter when we write system documentation.

Comment: @ivarne and instead of going to a file and changing that, you prefer going to source code, which needs to be recompiled and re-distributed, as opposed to just updating the resource file. The fact that it adds some complexity in managing the file isn't a good argument. It's quite simple actually... I'd say around a couple of hours of development. You have to also take into account the long-term cost of this. Modify the source code implies re-testing, re-compiling, binary versioning etc...

Comment: A separate file probably lends itself more easily to different (human) languages too.  This is the right solution.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore As explained in the update to the question I do not write the c code by hand. The C code and the documentation is generated by a ruby script, based on the options and data given to the script.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building an application under Windows then the place for string literals is in the resource file - much easier to manage and supports translation.

Embedding strings directly isn't a good idea.

Comment: The target is to write cross platform C code that can be compiled and linked into programs using it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, it's probably easier to use a separate file, although this does introduce added complexities when it comes to deployment.  Alternatively, what I do a lot is to use a table of strings, each line in a separate entry:

```
char const* doc[] =
{
    "first line",
    "next line",
    //  ...
    "last line",
};
```

And to output, something like:

```
std::copy( begin(doc), end(doc),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
```

This seems to work well, and allows visual formatting.  Or other: in
vim, I'll mark the block and do `:s/ *"\(.*\)",/\1/` (just a standard
search and replace on the marked block), then format using whatever
tools are appropriate, either using the internal commands of the editor
(fairly simple), or by piping to some external command (which can be as
complicated as you like), and finally, `:s/.*/        "&",/` to restore
the C++ punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question; others have already answered it. However, comments are bad for posting code.

Your code should be fixed to something like this code (not compiled nor tested):

```
const char *doc_arr[] = {
    "Documentation for my program\n",
    "\n",
    "This is a seccond line\n",
    // and so on ....
};
int doc_arr_length = 203; // number lines in doc_arr
char doc[3502];           // number of bytes in dockumentation

const char* doc_ptr = doc;

for(int i = 0; i < doc_arr_length; i++){
    int length = strlen(doc_arr[i]);
    memcpy(doc_ptr, 
           doc_arr[i], 
           sizeof(char)*length + 1);
    doc_ptr += length;
}
```

Issues fixed:

- Whenever dealing with string literals, always use const pointers. Modifying a string literal through a pointer, intentionally or unintentionally, invoked undefined behavior.
- You loop condition was incorrect and the loop was strange.

Optimizations:

- Calling strcat repeatedly in a loop like this will be extremely inefficient. For each loop iteration, strcat() would have to go through the steadily growing string in search of the null termination. By keeping track of the last position through a pointer, your program doesn't need to perform this slow lookup at every lap in the loop.
- When introducing the pointer mentioned above, we will need to know the string length of the string to copy. Since we have now made this information available by calling strlen(), we don't need to call "slow" functions like strcat() and strcpy() that search for a null termination. We could use strncpy() or memcpy() instead. I picked memcpy() since the extra feature in strncpy() (appending additional null terminations) is useless in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree. This is what I would have written if I liked the concept of having two copies of the doc in memory (I do not think that it maters, but it's annoying me when I see it). I just wrote it as a short illustration so that I would not make you waste time on what I already had.